# How to provide a custom style to React navigation drawer screen title

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using React Navigation drawer and i want to have a different fontSize (custom styling) for each drawer screen title. Changing the labelStyle in the drawerContentOptions would change the fontSize for all the drawer screen titles and I wanna have each one customized.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerStyle={{
    backgroundColor: Colors.mainBackground,
    width: WIDTH * 0.6,
  }}

  drawerContentOptions={{
    activeTintColor: Colors.mainForeGround,
    itemStyle: { marginVertical: 8, marginHorizontal: 8 },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 18,
    },
  }}
>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}
    options={{
      title: 'Profile Name',
      drawerIcon: ({ color }) => {
        return <Icon name={'account'} size={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
      },
    }}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}
    options={{
      title: 'Shopping menu',
      drawerIcon: ({ color }) => {
        return <Icon name={'menu'} size={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
      },
    }}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart}
    options={{
      title: 'Shopping cart',
      drawerIcon: ({ color }) => {
        return <Icon name={'cart'} size={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
      },
    }}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}
    options={{
      title: 'Settings',
      drawerIcon: ({ color }) => {
        return <Icon2 name={'settings'} size={ICON_SIZE} color={color} />
      },
    }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawer.Navigator provides a prop called `drawContent` which needs to return a React component which will be used to render the contents of the drawer.

Usage:

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
     <Here goes your code for rendering individual elements of your drawer>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Article} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

For full example, refer [link](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=createDrawerNavigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fdrawer-with-style.js)